# Anyone here ever having trouble such as auth::user() make us confusing?

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

So on database, user who have named **Mirna** has a **hrd** role.
And i have a code like this.

```
<p class="text-muted">Your Current Role is
<strong>{{Auth::user()->role}}</strong>
</p>
```

The result is not hrd, but it is shows a other value.
Confusing right?

And another confusing problem is..
i have a menu that each menu have each authorization too. 
so the code is sounds like this

```
@if(Auth::user()->role=='hrd')
<li><a class="sidebar-sub-toggle"><i class="ti-layout-grid2-alt"></i> Candidate<span
class="sidebar-collapse-icon ti-angle-down"></span></a>
<ul>
<li><a href="/candidate/managements">Candidates Data</a></li>
<li><a href="/candidate/interviewed">Candidates Interviewed</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
@endif
```

if you know this route and how's the result. It should shows us menu candidate, candidates data and candidates interviewed if auth logged in have a hrd roles, am i right?

but the result is
[this is the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qf5PH.png)
can you help me?
Whats wrong on my code?

Thanks before guys

Comment: Is `role` a column in `users` table?

Comment: yes sir. And clearly have no spaces or something else

Comment: Stupid ideea: use   auth()->user()->role     instead of Auth::user()......